# Prevent react component from rendering twice when using redux with componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React component that dispatches a redux state change in its `componentWillMount` function. The reason is that when the component is loaded, it needs to get the `id` from the url (powered by `react-router`), and trigger an action that sets up the state with that `id`'s data.

Here is the component:

```
class Editor extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        const { dispatch, params } = this.props
        dispatch(editItem(params.id))
    }

    render() {
        const item = this.props.item
        console.log("Editing", item)
    }
}

export default connect(state => ({item: state.item}))(Editor)
```

Here's the catch: `render` is getting called twice. `item` is undefined on the first call, and valid on the second. Ideally, it should only be called once `this.props.item` actually exists (after the `editItem` action has been dispatched and run).

According to the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount): "If you call `setState` within this method, `render()` will see the updated state and will be executed only once despite the state change."

In redux, `dispatch` is the equivalent of calling `setState`, as it results in a state change. However, I'm guessing something in the way `connect` works is still causing `render` to be called twice.

Is there a way around this besides adding a line like `if (!item) return;` ?

Answer (score 8):

One thing you might do is create a higher order component that handles the basic pattern of loading a different component (or no component) before the required props are loaded.

```
export const LoaderWrapper = function(hasLoaded, Component, LoaderComponent, onLoad) {
    return props => {
        if (hasLoaded(props)) {
            return <Component {...props} />
        }
        else {
            if (onLoad) onLoad(props)

            return { LoaderComponent ? <LoaderComponent /> : null }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can wrap your component before connecting it to get the desired behaviour.

```
export default connect(state => ({item: state.item}))(LoaderWrapper(
    ((props) => !!props.item),
    Editor,
    null,
    (props) => props.dispatch(editItem(props.params.id))
))
```

You might want to add some currying magic to make sure you can compose these kinds of wrapper functions more nicely. Take a look at [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) for more info.

Comment: `return LoaderComponent ? <LoaderComponent /> : null`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's already an issue in the react-redux library.

https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/issues/210

Answer (score 1):

What does editItem do? Does it add item to the redux state or is it there already?

If it is adding I imagine what is happening is that a render cycle happens with the current props, ie item being blank.
Then it gets rendered again when the props have changed, via setting the item.

One approach to fixing this sort of thing is to create a higher order component that wraps Editor and calls the dispatch action the rendering though is set either to a loading screen or and empty div until item is set. That way you can be assured that Editor will have an item.

But without knowing what editItem does it's sort of hard to know. Maybe you could paste the code for that?