# React router loading data each time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, reactjs

I am new to using React and React Router.

The home page (home component) loads data via an ajax request to the server which displays the data.

Then people can navigate within the app using react router. But when someone goes back to the home page (home component) the ajax call is again made to the server which is unnecessary.

So basically when you're navigating within components using react router each time a component is loaded ajax calls are made every time.

Is there something we can do to maybe cache the data like in Angular where we don't have to make the ajax calls again and again when a component is loaded.

Thanks

```
class NewComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data : []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
      let length =  Object.keys(this.state.data).length;

      if(length === 0){
        let req = new Request('https://example.com/json', {
          mode: 'cors',
          method: 'get'
        });

        this.serverRequest = fetch(req).then(function (result) {
          return result.json()
        }).then(function(j){
          this.setState({
            data: j.up
          })

        }.bind(this));

      }
  }

render(){
    return(
    some html
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code to illustrate the issue?

Comment: I assume you have perused this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347481/prevent-react-component-from-rendering-twice-when-using-redux-with-componentwill

Comment: I am not using redux, so basically i have to create a parent component and add this componet as a child passing data as props?

Comment: The short answer is: you need a place to store the data. Either in top level / shared component, or some store that lives outside of React like redux / mobx etc etc, potentially localstorage even.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to store all your state in your topmost app component, which should only re-mount when the page is reloaded. That way the state can stay in there, and be passed down to child components.

If it's a larger project, you might consider using a state management system alongside React like [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux).

Another idea is to move your ajax functions out into their own module, which gets imported into your component. Then you can place some caching in your ajax module, away from your component.