# React + Redux: Separating the presentation from the data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a weather app with React & Redux. I've decided to venture into uncharted waters as a noob to React & Redux. I'm splitting things up into presentational components and their respective container that will handle the data. I'm having some problems wrapping my head around this though. It might come down to how I'm trying to do it I'm just really unsure.

Right now I have `SearchBar`, `CurrentWeather`, & `Forecast` components and an `AppContainer` that I'm trying to integrate those components into. I have the `SearchBar` component integrated into the `AppContainer` so far and it is working with no problems. Here is where I am getting confused. So I have provided the needed actions and components to the container and the container has been `connected` so when the user does a search the api call will be made and the state will update through the reducers.

That data should be available through `mapStateToProps` now correct?

How can I go about using that data after the user has performed the action but have it not be used upon the initial render? If `AppContainer` is rendering these three components I will obviously be passing props to them so they render and function as they are expected to. I'm thinking this is where a lifecycle could be used I'm just unsure of which or how to use them. My code for the `AppContainer`, `SearcBar`, & `CurrentWeather` are below. `CurrentWeather` & `Forecast` are nearly identical (only providing different data from different endpoints for the api) so I did not provide it. I also didn't provide the actions or reducers because I know they work fine before I decided to attempt this refactor. Maybe I need more than one container to pull this off? Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks all and have a good night.

** Do have a side question: on `_weatherSearch` I have `event.preventDefault();` because the `SearchBar` is a form element. Do I even need to provide this? If `event` is not what is being passed but the `term` I think no. The `event` is being used as seen below in the form element of `SearchBar`:

`onSubmit={event => getWeather(event.target.value)}`

App Container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCurrentWeather, fetchForecast } from '../actions/actions';

import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import CurrentWeather from '../components/CurrentWeather';

class AppContainer extends Component {

  _weatherSearch(term) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Here is where we go to fetch weather data.
    this.props.fetchCurrentWeather(term);
    this.props.fetchForecast(term);
    }

  render() {
    const getWeather = term => {this._weatherSearch(term);};
    return (
      <div className="application">
        <SearchBar getWeather={getWeather}/>
        <CurrentWeather />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ current, forecast }) => {
  return {
    current,
    forecast
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
  { fetchCurrentWeather, fetchForecast })(AppContainer);
```

SearchBar:

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchBar = ({ getWeather }) => {
  return(
    <form className='input-group' onSubmit={event => getWeather(event.target.value)}>
      <input
      className='form-control'
      placeholder='Search a US City' />
      <span className='input-group-btn'>
        <button className='btn btn-secondary' type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </span>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

CurrentWeather: *NOTE: I have not removed any of the logic or data processing from `CurrentWeather` yet so it has not been refactored to a presentational only component yet.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {unitConverter} from '../conversions/conversions_2.0';

export class CurrentWeather extends Component {
    _renderCurrentWeather(cityData) {
        const name = cityData.name;
        const {temp, pressure, humidity} = cityData.main;
        const {speed, deg} = cityData.wind;
        const {sunrise, sunset} = cityData.sys;
        return (
            <tr key={name}>
                <td>{unitConverter.toFarenheit(temp)} F</td>
                <td>{unitConverter.toInchesHG(pressure)}"</td>
                <td>{humidity}%</td>
                <td>{unitConverter.toMPH(speed)}mph {unitConverter.toCardinal(deg)}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }

    render() {
        let currentWeatherData = [];
        if (this.props.current) {
            currentWeatherData = this.props.current.map(this._renderCurrentWeather);
        }
        return (
            <table className="table table-reflow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Temperature</th>
                        <th>Pressure</th>
                        <th>Humidity</th>
                        <th>Wind</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {currentWeatherData}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({current}) {
    return {current};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CurrentWeather);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your render function is very dynamic. You can omit anything you like:

```
class AppContainer extends Component {

  _weatherSearch(term) {
    // event.preventDefault(); We can't do this because we don't have an event here...

    this.props.fetchCurrentWeather(term);
    this.props.fetchForecast(term);
    }

  render() {
    const getWeather = term => { this._weatherSearch(term); };
    return (
      <div className="application">
        <SearchBar getWeather={getWeather}/>
        { Boolean(this.props.current) && <CurrentWeather /> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ current }) => ({ current });

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
  { fetchCurrentWeather, fetchForecast })(AppContainer);
```

This is how you deal with missing data. You just either show nothing, or a message to search first, or if it's loading,you can show a spinner or throbber.

The technique used above to hide `CurrentWeather` is to pass a Boolean to React if we're wanting to hide the component. React ignores `true`, `false`, `null` and `undefined`.

Note that it's a good idea to only ever pass data in mapStateToProps that you'll actually be using inside the component itself. In your code you're passing `current` and `forecast` but you don't use them.

Redux will rerender when any of the `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` or `props` data changes. By returning data you'll never use you instruct Redux to rerender when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a react-redux noob myself :-) and I've come across similar issues.

As far as I can tell, the container/presentational separation you've made looks good, but you can go even a step further and separate the container's **fetching** and **mounting**.

The solution I'm referring to is what people variously call "higher-order components" and "wrapper components": (the code below isn't tested - it's just for illustration purposes)

```
import {connect} from blah;

const AppWrap = (Wrapped) => {
  class AppWrapper extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {foo: false};
    }
    componentWillMount() {
      this.props.actions.fooAction()
      .then(() => this.setState({foo: false}));
    }
    render() {
      return (<Wrapped {...this.props} foo={this.state.foo}/>);
    }
  }

  function mapState(state) { blah }
  function mapDispatch(dispatch) { blah }

  return connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(AppWrapper);
}

export default AppWrap;
```

Notice the `= (Wrapped) => {` part at the top. That is what's doing the actual "wrapping", and the argument can be named anything so long as you refer to it in the render hook.

Now inside your AppContainer, you get a `this.props.foo` which acts as a flag telling you that `fooAction()` has completed, and you can use it to render your presentational components accordingly. Until fooAction completes, you can be sure that the `foo` passed into AppContainer will be `false`.

To put what I just said into code, your AppContainer might look something like this:

```
import AppWrapper from './AppWrapper';

class AppContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (!this.props.foo) ? <div>bar</div> : (
      <div blah>
        <SearchBar blah/>
        <CurrentWeather blah/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppWrapper(AppContainer);
```

The benefit of using a wrapper component like this is that

- you can take more control over how and when exactly the data gets rendered
- account for "loading" mechanisms and logic
- avoid quirky problems like having to make [dispatches within componentWillMount](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/210) hooks and having to deal with [the consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347481/prevent-react-component-from-rendering-twice-when-using-redux-with-componentwill).

Take a look at this blog post for more information about HoCs: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750

Comment: does your `AppWrapper` contain the logic for the presentational components then and you just pass `props` down to the child components being rendered in `AppContainer`?

Comment: I guess where you place the logic is a preferential thing. I was thinking along the lines where everything in just as you were doing before, except you take out the asynchronous actions, put them into `AppWrapper`, and turn the "state" of those actions into a prop. So in summary, wrapper contains async actions, container contains logic, components contain jsx.